# How to add www to the sub-folders of URL in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, jomres

Here is the link of subfolder

https://example.com/abc/ i want to add www to subfolders also like this https://www.example.com/abc/

Answer (score 0):

To force WWW, simply use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```